# Why does constructor with arg undefine the default constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, default-constructor

Consider   -

```
public class Class_A {

    public void func() {...}

    public void func(int a){...}
```

All three -

```
Class_A a = new Class_A(); // legal
a.func(); // legal
a.func(1); // legal
```

But After *constructor with arg* like `public Class_A (int a){...}` is added to `Class_A` , the *default constructor* become to be -

```
Class_A a = new Class_A(); // The constructor Class_A() is undefined
```

Thats force me to add `public Class_A() {/*Do Nothing*/}` into `Class_A` .

Since each class has *default constructor*  , why doesn't both *default constructor* and *constructor with arg* can exist together just same  `func()` and `func(int a)` are ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it has default constructor unless you define your own constructor, in this case you need to re define default constructor

Answer (score 2):

Because If you write a constructor, compiler wouldn't write a default constructor for you. you have to write one explicitly.

From [**JLS**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9):

> If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default
>   constructor with no formal parameters and no throws clause is
>   implicitly declared.

Answer (score 1):

It's the other way around.

If you don't have any constructor you get the no-arg one by default.

Answer (score 0):

The name "default constructor" implies that it is provided when you don't provide one yourself. As soon as you provide your own constructor, the compiler will not generate a default constructor for you.

Be careful not to confuse the default constructor with the no-arg constructor. These are two entirely different things.